# How to accumulate values at hourly granularity given half hour granularity?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
DateTime              SENSOR   PROD
2019-04-01 00:00:00   0        0.0
2019-04-01 00:30:00   1        10.0
2019-04-01 01:00:00   1        5.0
2019-04-01 01:30:00   1        1.0
2019-04-01 02:00:00   1        12.0
2019-04-01 02:30:00   0        0.0
```

The values are given at half hourly granularity. I should sum `PROD` up at hourly granularity to get the following result.

```
DateTime              PROD
2019-04-01 00:00:00   10.0
2019-04-01 01:00:00   6.0
2019-04-01 02:00:00   12.0
```

Comment: check resample sum ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen: do you mean something like `df.resample('1H')["PROD"].sum()`? If so, I get error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.resample` like so:

```
df.resample('H').sum()
```

To use `resample` though, you need to make sure your index is a `DatetimeIndex`. I think there are a few ways to do this, but you could try:

```
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resample`:

```
df.set_index('DateTime').resample('H').sum().drop('SENSOR', axis=1)
```

---

```
                     PROD
DateTime                 
2019-04-01 00:00:00  10.0
2019-04-01 01:00:00   6.0
2019-04-01 02:00:00  12.0
```

**Note**: if your `DateTime` column is not yet in datetime format, first do:

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html)

```
df.set_index('DateTime').drop('SENSOR',1).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1h')).aggregate(np.sum)
```

Output:

```
                    PROD
DateTime        
2019-04-01 00:00:00 10.0
2019-04-01 01:00:00 6.0
2019-04-01 02:00:00 12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`resample` supports option `on` to specify the column using for resample instead of index. So, you don't need to set_index to `datetimeindex`. Just specify the column name in `on`

```
df.resample('H', on='DateTime').PROD.sum()

Out[1948]:
DateTime
2019-04-01 00:00:00    10.0
2019-04-01 01:00:00     6.0
2019-04-01 02:00:00    12.0
Freq: H, Name: PROD, dtype: float64
```

---

Another way is using `groupby` on the casting down of `df.DateTime` to `datetime64[h]`

```
df.groupby(df.DateTime.astype('datetime64[h]')).PROD.sum()

Out[8]:
DateTime
2019-04-01 00:00:00    10.0
2019-04-01 01:00:00     6.0
2019-04-01 02:00:00    12.0
Name: PROD, dtype: float64
```